# How to achieve this result in R

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics, dataset

R Version 2.11.1 32-bit on Windows 7

I have two data sets as shown below:

data_set_A:

```
USER_B   ACTION
10       0.1
11       0.3
12       0.1
```

data_set_B:

```
USER_A   USER_B   ACTION
1        10       0.2
1        11       0.1
1        15       0.1
2        12       0.2
```

How to add the `ACTION` of `USER_B` from `data_set_A` to `data_set_B`? The `USER_B` in `data_set_A` is a subset of `USER_B` in `data_set_B`.

for the example above, it may be:

```
USER_A   USER_B   ACTION
1        10       0.2+0.1
1        11       0.1+0.3
1        15       0.1
2        12       0.2+0.1
```

In `data_set_B` I don't need to consider the `USER_A`, just consider the `USER_B` appear in `data_set_A`.

I wonder if it could be achieved without doing one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dfa <- data.frame(
        user_b = 10:12,
        action = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.1)
)

dfb <- data.frame(
        user_a = c(1, 1, 1, 2),
        user_b = c(10, 11, 15, 12),
        action = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2)
)


action <- dfa$action[match(dfb$user_b, dfa$user_b)]
action[is.na(action)] <- 0
dfb$action <- dfb$action + action
dfb

  user_a user_b action
1      1     10    0.3
2      1     11    0.4
3      1     15    0.1
4      2     12    0.3
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to do the equivalent of a database merge on the two data sets to form the action pairs you want and then sum those. Using @Andrie's example code:

```
dfa <- data.frame(
        user_b = 10:12,
        action = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.1)
)

dfb <- data.frame(
        user_a = c(1, 1, 1, 2),
        user_b = c(10, 11, 15, 12),
        action = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2)
)
```

#### Solution Code

I'll first present the full solution and then explain the steps:

```
mdat <- merge(dfb, dfa, by = "user_b", all.x = TRUE)
res <- data.frame(mdat[,c(2,1)],
                  action = rowSums(mdat[, c("action.x", "action.y")], 
                                   na.rm = TRUE))
res <- res[order(res$user_a, res$user_b),]
```

`res` now contains the results.

#### Explanation

We first merge the two data frames, matching on `user_b`:

```
## merge the data
mdat <- merge(dfb, dfa, by = "user_b", all.x = TRUE)
mdat
```

giving:

```
> mdat
  user_b user_a action.x action.y
1     10      1      0.2      0.1
2     11      1      0.1      0.3
3     12      2      0.2      0.1
4     15      1      0.1       NA
```

Then we just use this object to create the result data frame, and sum the two `action.` columns row-wise:

```
## format the merged data with summed `action`
res <- data.frame(mdat[,c(2,1)],
                  action = rowSums(mdat[, c("action.x", "action.y")], 
                                   na.rm = TRUE))
## reorder
res <- res[order(res$user_a, res$user_b),]
res
```

resulting in

```
> res
  user_a user_b action
1      1     10    0.3
2      1     11    0.4
4      1     15    0.1
3      2     12    0.3
```

Comment: +1 For showing merge. Especially for showing that you may wish to reorder the merged data.frame - I spent several hours last month debugging some code.  It turned out that the bug was introduced as a result of my erroneous assumption that the merged data.frame would have the same order as the original (using merge(..., all.x=TRUE)).